# Change Owl Carousel options if items count is smaller than page size

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I have a carousel that the number of its items are not always the same and I want to change some options of the carousel when the items count is smaller than the page size.

Here is what I tried but it doesn't work :

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    rtl: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 3000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    dots: false,
    rewind: false,
    checkVisible: false,
    responsive: {
        500: {
            items: 2
        },
        700: {
            items: 3
        },
        900: {
            items: 4
        },
        1100: {
            items: 5
        },
        1300: {
            items: 6
        }
    },
    onInitialize: function (e) {
        if (e.item.count < e.page.size) {
            owl.data('owl.carousel').options.loop = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Carousel work properly but callback function doesn't work and I get `Cannot read property 'options' of undefined` error in the chrome's console.

Answer (score 1):

```
responsive: {
        500: {
            items: 2,
            loop: function () {
                if ($(this).find('.owl-item').length > 2) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        },
        700: {
            items: 3,
            loop: function () {
                if ($(this).find('.owl-item').length > 3) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        },
        900: {
            items: 4,
            loop: function () {
                if ($(this).find('.owl-item').length > 4) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        },
        1100: {
            items: 5,
            loop: function () {
                if ($(this).find('.owl-item').length > 5) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        },
        1300: {
            items: 6,
            loop: function () {
                if ($(this).find('.owl-item').length > 6) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```